# Conditional drag and drop in QML

Tags: qt, qml

This code generates two drop areas and one dragable rectangle of blue colour.
I want the blue rectangle to be able to be dropped in only the gold coloured drop area. The other drop area should refuse to accept this particular rectangle.

What can I write to make this happen?

So, in this code the DropArea coloured 'gold' has the keys 'xyz' and I have set `Drag.keys: "xyz"` to blue rectangle which is supposed to be dragged.

Now, that blue rectangle is being excepted in the other drop area but not in the gold one.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: "Drag & drop example"
    visible: true

    Repeater {
        model: 1
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 50
            height: 50
            z: mouseArea.drag.active ||  mouseArea.pressed ? 2 : 1
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
            x: Math.random() * (win.width / 2 - 100)
            y: Math.random() * (win.height - 100)
            property point beginDrag
            property bool caught: false
            border { width:2; color: "white" }
            radius: 5
            Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
                color: "white"
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
                Drag.keys: "xyz"
                onPressed: {
                    rect.beginDrag = Qt.point(rect.x, rect.y);
                }
                onReleased: {
                    if(!rect.caught) {
                        backAnimX.from = rect.x;
                        backAnimX.to = beginDrag.x;
                        backAnimY.from = rect.y;
                        backAnimY.to = beginDrag.y;
                        backAnim.start()
                    }
                }

            }
            ParallelAnimation {
                id: backAnim
                SpringAnimation { id: backAnimX; target: rect; property: "x"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
                SpringAnimation { id: backAnimY; target: rect; property: "y"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        x: 0; y: 0
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "gold"
        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            keys: "xyz"
            onEntered: drag.source.caught = true;
            onExited: drag.source.caught = false;
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        x: 0; y: 300
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "red"
        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            keys: "abc"
            onEntered: drag.source.caught = true;
            onExited: drag.source.caught = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and found what you were doing wrong. You have `Drag.keys` set in the wrong place. Instead of setting it in the `MouseArea`, set it in the object that gets dragged.

```
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            ...
            Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
            Drag.keys: "xyz"

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
                ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are we not supposed to set the keys in droparea too? How will it know which keys to accept?

Comment: Yes, leave that part of your code the same. Just change where you put Drag.keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [keys](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html#keys-prop) property from the `DropArea` and related classes. As stated in the Qt docs, this is used as filter for the drag-n-drop events

```
...

Rectangle { 
    Drag.keys: "gold" //only allow drag to gold
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
        onPressed: {
            rect.beginDrag = Qt.point(rect.x, rect.y);
        }
        ...
    }
}

...

Rectangle
{
    x: 0; y: 0
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "gold"
    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        keys: "gold"
        onEntered: drag.source.caught = true;
        onExited: drag.source.caught = false;
    }
}

Rectangle
{
    x: 0; y: 300
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "red"
    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        keys: "red"
        onEntered: drag.source.caught = true;
        onExited: drag.source.caught = false;
    }
}
```

You should not omit the key for the red Rectangle, since otherwise it will accept all drag sources.

---

Also in case you want multiple sources to be accepted, you can specify a list of keys:

```
DropArea {
    keys: ["gold", "nuggets", "at", "the", "end", "of", "a", "rainbow"]
}
```

The same goes for the drag sources:

```
Drag.keys: ["gold", "bar", "in", "the", "back"]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question. I request you to help me.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I have edited my answer as well

Comment: My understanding is that key drag "xyz" should be accepted in the drop area with key "xyz". My edited code refuses to do that. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: See the answer of JarMan, I also updated my question to it (btw, you should probably not have edited the updated part in the original question)